# Communicator Messages not being saved to Outlook due to Outlook Integration error

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, office-communicator-2007

For the most part my Office Communicator appears to be configured correctly.  I can login to my work account and see the work contact list.  Outlook is working perfectly had a weird profile problem initially but that was fixed.

Unfortunately, even though I have set the setting that says:

> Save my instant message conversations
>   in the Outlook Conversation History
>   folder.

My conversations have stopped saving to the **Outlook Conversation History folder**.  Also I have a yellow warning message on top of the server icon next to the status field.  When I hover or click on the message, it says there is an Outlook Integration Error.  The administrator is having trouble figuring out what is causing it.

What can cause Outlook Integration Errors in Communicator and how do I go about trouble shooting them?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. My sys admin recommended a reboot (as does [this thread](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ucintegrationwithexchange/thread/6915a50c-b69e-43c0-b2a8-564bca4c35f3)), but that takes ~30 min on my system so I avoid it if I can.

What worked for me instead was shutting down Outlook (entirely), then shutting down Communicator (*Note: you may have to do this from the sys tray; if you just close the main Communicator window, the program will still be running in the background; take a look at Task Manager Processes, just to be sure*). Then restart Outlook and, once it is running and connected to Exchange, restart Communicator. (In my case, I continued to get a warning message on the main Communicator window for the first few moments while it was establishing a connection to Exchange, but it eventually disappeared and everything was back to normal.)

If that does not resolve it for you, or for further assistance, refer to this Support page: [How to troubleshoot Office Communicator and Office Outlook integration issues](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2373585)